# How to unit test the state of props using mocha chai and enzyme?

Tags: javascript, redux, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

I'm trying to unit test onClick the state of the props in my component clear.

I tried doing it this way:

```
props = {
    attributeTableData: data,
    clearMessage: onClickMethod,
    reset: () => { },
    resetAttributeTable: () => { },
    statusMessage: {
        messageType: 'message-success',
        userMessage: 'Template has been saved successfully. Please wait …see your results display with the latest'
    },
    submitTemplateCreationStatus: () => { },
    templateAttributeFormData: () => { },
    templateFormSubmission: true,
    templateAttributeFormSubmission: true,
    templateFormData: () => { },
    userRoles: new Set(['admin'])
};
let emptyStatusMessage = {};
actualComponent = shallow(<CreateTemplateResults { ...props } />);
actualComponent.instance().resetForms();
expect(onClickMethod.called).to.be.true;
expect(actualComponent.state('statusMessage')).to.eql(emptyStatusMessage)
```

But I get:

> "     TypeError: ShallowWrapper::state("statusMessage") requires that
>   `state` not be `null` or `undefined`"

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a shallow render of `<CreateTemplateResults />`, but never passing `actualComponent.setState(nextState)`. Therefore, when you are trying to access the state on your last line, it is throwing an error because state is `null`/`undefined`.

[shallow().setState](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.html)